# Is it possible in ElasticSearch to search from the output of previous query (multi layer filtration)

Tags: rest, elasticsearch, django-rest-framework, full-text-search, elk

We have around 36K products. I am trying to do something like this in elastic.
Select all documents from index where brand = 'search_text', from this result, would like to further search pharma = 'search_text' and so on multiple search within the results derived.

Also with every search want to remove the brand from search_text, then remove pharma and so on, to ultimately have len = 0 of the seach_text.

Initial Search_text = "Digene Mint 200ml Gel"

Searching for Brand in documents.

Initial Result:

```
{"index":{"_id":3}}
{"title": "Digene Tablet 9's", "old_sku_id": "MBPHM01BTABABBT000835", "brand_text": "Digene", "manufacturer_text": "Abbott", "generic_name_id": null, "uom_text": null, "pack_type_text": null, "pack_quantity": null, "pharma_formulation": "Tablet"}
{"index":{"_id":4}}
{"title": "Digene Mint 200ml Gel", "old_sku_id": "MBPHM01BGELABBT000008", "brand_text": "Digene", "manufacturer_text": "Abbott", "generic_name_id": 8128, "uom_text": null, "pack_type_text": null, "pack_quantity": 200, "pharma_formulation": "Gel"}
{"index":{"_id":5}}
{"title": "Digene Mint 450ml Gel", "old_sku_id": "MBPHM01BGELABBT000009", "brand_text": "Digene", "manufacturer_text": "Abbott", "generic_name_id": 8128, "uom_text": null, "pack_type_text": null, "pack_quantity": 450, "pharma_formulation": "Gel"}
```

Search_text should now be : "Mint 200ml Gel" (brand_text deleted from search_text)

Now searching for pharma_formulation:

Result Expected:

```
{"title": "Digene Mint 200ml Gel", "old_sku_id": "MBPHM01BGELABBT000008", "brand_text": "Digene", "manufacturer_text": "Abbott", "generic_name_id": 8128, "uom_text": null, "pack_type_text": null, "pack_quantity": 200, "pharma_formulation": "Gel"}

{"title": "Digene Mint 450ml Gel", "old_sku_id": "MBPHM01BGELABBT000009", "brand_text": "Digene", "manufacturer_text": "Abbott", "generic_name_id": 8128, "uom_text": null, "pack_type_text": null, "pack_quantity": 450, "pharma_formulation": "Gel"}
```

Search_text should now be : "Mint 200ml" (pharma_formulation deleted from search_text)
Search for pack_quantity

Expected Output:

```
{"title": "Digene Mint 200ml Gel", "old_sku_id": "MBPHM01BGELABBT000008", "brand_text": "Digene", "manufacturer_text": "Abbott", "generic_name_id": 8128, "uom_text": null, "pack_type_text": null, "pack_quantity": 200, "pharma_formulation": "Gel"}
```

Search_text now should be : "Mint ml"

We do not want to search title for some reason.

For layered have done this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs":{
    "my_filter":{
      "filters":{
        "filters":{
          "Brand":{
            "match":{
              "brand_text":"Digene Mint 200ml Gel"
            }
          },
          "ph":{
            "match":{
              "pharma_formulation":"Digene Mint 200ml Gel"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you give sample documents and expected results?

Comment: Added samples and examples

Comment: so what would be your final result just `"title": "Digene Mint 200ml Gel"` ?

Comment: Yes "title": "Digene Mint 200ml Gel" is the final one.